# Bounded convex function on $[0,\infty)$ interval

Tags: real-analysis

It's a modification of a question regarding a proof for a bounded convex function on $\mathbb{R}$ to be constant. We have $f:[0,\infty)\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that is twice differentiable, bounded and convex. One must show $f'(x)\leq 0 \ \ \forall_{x\in[0,\infty)}$

I'm trying to think out of the box, examine the definition, but nothing comes to my mind. It's rather simple, I'm sure of it. How do I start?

Comment: What does convexity mean in terms of the derivative? If you had $f'(x_0) > 0$, why would $f$ then be unbounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Note that for all $x,y$, there is $t\in [0,1]$ such that $$f'(x)-f'(y)=f''(tx+(1-t)y)(x-y). \tag{1}$$

Conclude from $(1)$ that $f'$ is an non decreasing function. Now assume that there is $z$ such that $f'(z)>0$. How do you get a contradiction?